# If the puppet main manifest is site.pp, then are files in the manifests and modules directory ignored?

Tags: linux, module, manifest, puppet, administration

By default site.pp is the main manifest, and I noticed that whatever I type in this file gets recognized by puppet.

However, when I try to create something in either the manifests or modules directory, puppet seems to ignore it.

Since the main manifest is site.pp, does that mean that it ignores whatever is in those directories? Do I have to write something in site.pp in order for it to recognize other modules or manifests?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand as long as your puppet.conf file is configured with a "basemodulepath" value then anything you put in a directory defined by that basemodulepath should be autoloaded.

From there all that you need to do is define your node inside of site.pp with the module that you have created, using an include.

I'm using Puppet Enterprise in a paid lab, so YMMV, but I just did this in a lab exercise and had no issues. My basemodulepath is:

`basemodulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules`

I defined a motd module under the path: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/motd/, so my module is autoloaded (it's a subdirectory of /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules which is part of the configured basemodulepath).

Now that that was done, all that I need to do inside of site.pp was define the node I wanted to apply the module to, and include the motd module:

```
node 'mynode_certname'{
    include motd
}
```

I hope this helps you out.